# I skipped a lot of lectures, how do I even integrate this?

Tags: integration

$f (x) = e^{2x} \cdot sin(3x)$

I did integration by parts

$\rightarrow$ $sin(3x) \cdot \frac{e^{2x}}{2}-\frac{3}{2} \int cos(3x)\cdot e^{2x} dx$

This is where I am, if I do another partial integration then I will have a infinite loop.

I don't know what to try to solve it.

EDIT:
Second partial: $cos(3x)\frac{e^{2x}}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\int sin(3x) e^{2x}dx$

If I trace back(?) the second partial to the first:
$sin(3x)\frac{e^{2x}}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\int cos(3x)\frac{e^{2x}}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\int sin(3x) e^{2x}dx$

EDIT2: The solution should be:
$\large\frac{4}{13}(\large\frac{e^{2x}sin(3x)}{2}-\large\frac{3}{4}e^{2x}cos(3x))+c$

Comment: Did you try the infinite loop ? (maybe it will not be infinite)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Well, i partial 3 times on that and i always got sin, cos, -sin and so on, and $\frac {e^{2x}}{2}$ will be the same every time. But that could be that is made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: yes but coefficients are different so $I=g(x)+aI\implies I=g(x)/(1-a)$...

Comment: The second partial looks like this: $cos(3x)\cdot\frac{e^{2x}}{2}-\int -3sin(3x)\cdot\frac{e^{2x}}{2}dx$ and if i trace back(?) to the first: $sin(3x)\cdot\frac{e^{2x}}{2}\int cos(3x)\cdot\frac{e^{2x}}{2}-\int -3sin(3x)\cdot\frac{e^{2x}}{2}dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let us expand our goal a little bit. We want to find an expression for the integral:

$$\ S(a,b) = \int e^{ax} sin(bx) dx$$

Notice that this integral is (sort of) related to its cosine counterpart, which is:

$$\ C(a,b) = \int e^{ax} cos(bx) dx$$

To deal with integrals of the type:

$$\ S(a,b) = \int e^{ax} \sin(bx) dx$$

and

$$\ C(a,b) = \int e^{ax} \cos(bx) dx$$

Together at once, instead of dealing with them individually, we can use Euler's identity, which states that

$$\ e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$$.

This can be derived from the Maclaurin series of $e^x$, $\operatorname{sinx}$ and $\operatorname{cos}x$. [The derivation for the same is linked here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgNtPOgFje0).

For $\theta = \ bx$, we have:

$$\ e^{ibx} = \cos(bx) + i\sin(bx)$$

Then, this implies that

$$\ C(a,b) + iS(a,b) = \int e^{ax}(\cos(bx) +i\sin(bx)) dx$$

$$ = \int e^{ax}\cdot e^{ibx} dx = \int e^{(a+ib)x} dx$$

Using the fact that

$$\int e^{ax}dx = \frac{e^{ax}}{a} + C$$

We can write:

$$ C(a,b) + iS(a,b) = \frac{e^{(a+ib)x}}{a+ib}+ C$$

Now, $S(a,b)$ is the Imaginary part of the expression in the RHS and $C(a,b)$ is the real part of the expression. Multiplying and dividing the expression by $(a-ib)$ and using the fact that $(a^2+b^2) = (a+ib)(a-ib)$, we get:

$$\big(\frac{e^{(a+ib)x}}{a+ib}\big) = \big(\frac{e^{ax}\cdot e^{ibx}\cdot (a-ib)}{a^2+b^2}\big) = \big(\frac{e^{ax}\cdot (cos(bx) + isin(bx))\cdot (a - ib)}{a^2+b^2}\big)$$

$$ = \big(\frac{e^{ax} \cdot (acos(bx) - ib cos(bx) + ia sin(bx) -i^2b sin(bx))}{a^2+b^2}$$

Note that $\ i^2 = -1$. Rearranging the real and imaginary parts, we get:

$$ C(a,b) + iS(a,b) =  \big(\frac{e^{ax} \cdot (acos(bx)  + b cos(bx))}{a^2+b^2}\big) + i \cdot \big(\frac{e^{ax} \cdot (asin(bx)  - bcos(bx))}{a^2+b^2}\big)+ C$$

Note that if we have the following equality

$$ a + ib = c + id$$

It is imperative that

$$ a = c$$

and

$$b = d$$

Thus, it clearly follows that:

$$\ S(a,b) = \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2} \cdot [a\sin(bx)- b\cos(bx)] + C $$

Just plug in $a=2$ and $b=3$ and you will have your answer.

Comment: Also, $$\ C(a,b,k) = \int e^{ax}cos(bx+k)\,dx=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}[a\cos(bx+k) + b\cos(bx+k)] + C $$

Comment: @ayan Yes. That follows after taking the real part.

Comment: @ScipioAemilianus There is a problem with this solution if the complex analysis is out of scope for solving this integral.

Comment: @VukJovovic Not really. Note that I only used complex numbers to combine two integrals into one. I didn't use contour integration or the residue theorem for the record.

Comment: Downvoter, can you explain why did you downvoted this post? Is any detail missing?

Comment: @ScipioAemilianus Yes, but you used Euler's identity. I am not saying that you used advanced complex analysis tools, but maybe the entire complex analysis is out of scope.

Comment: Okay, in that case, this may not be what OP wants. But I don't think he has explicitly forbade the use of Euler's formula.

Comment: @ScipioAemilianus Sorry, i really appreciate the work you put into this, but I don't understand a single line from it. I'm really sorry :c

Comment: @GooDinosaur Okay, bear with me. Let me elucidate every step I take in greater detail. Let me know if it then satisfies you and clears your doubts by accepting the answer.

Comment: @GooDinosaur what do you think now?

Comment: @ScipioAemilianus Thank you! This is way more understandable for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate two times, as you have done already. Now, you have:
$\int e^{2x}sin(3x)dx=sin(3x)+\frac{3}{2}(cos(3x)+\frac{3}{2}\int e^{2x}sin(3x)dx)$. In this case, you can make a substitution $t=\int e^{2x}sin(3x)dx$ and then solve the linear equation $t=sin(3x)+\frac{3}{2}(cos(3x)+\frac{3}{2}t)$. When you solve it, just add "$+c$" to the solution.

**EDIT:**
This solution is valid ONLY if you have integrated it properly. I have not done the integration myself. The procedure, though, is correct.

Comment: Why? Didn't I have: $sin(3x)-\frac{3}{2}\int cos(ex)\frac{e^{2x}}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\int sin(3x)e^{2x}dx$ Where does the first $\int$ mark went?

Comment: Solve the integral $\int cos(3x)e^{2x}dx$ by partial integration the same way you did the first time. You will end up with your original integral times some coefficient and some function as a byproduct of partial integration. You can then use the substitution and solve the linear equation. The solution of the equation will be your integral's solution, just add "$+c$".